# Why in filament widegt field report_year removed from requestsql?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

In laravel 9.52.10 app with filament 2.17.49 I make widget report based on data groupped by year with request:

```
class BannerClickedCountsByYears extends BaseWidget
{
    protected function getTableQuery(): Builder
    {

        $bannerClickedCountsByLocales= BannerClickedCount::selectRaw("  year(created_at) as report_year,  count(*) as report_count  ")
            ->groupByRaw('report_year')
            ->orderByRaw('min(created_at)');

        \Log::info(gettype($bannerClickedCountsByLocales));
        \Log::info(get_class($bannerClickedCountsByLocales));
        \Log::info(class_basename($bannerClickedCountsByLocales));
        \Log::info(json_encode($bannerClickedCountsByLocales));
        return $bannerClickedCountsByLocales;
    }
```

But I got error(I see that is select group report_year missing) :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'report_year' in 'group statement'
SELECT count(*) AS aggregate FROM `banner_clicked_counts` GROUP BY report_year ORDER BY min(created_at)
```

But in sql logs I see valid sql:

```
   SELECT   year(created_at)     AS report_year,  count(*)     AS report_count
    FROM `banner_clicked_counts`
    GROUP BY report_year
    ORDER BY min(created_at) limit 11 offset 0
```

which returned valid data
In log file I have next output :

```
[2023-06-30 07:56:11] local.INFO: object
[2023-06-30 07:56:11] local.INFO: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
[2023-06-30 07:56:11] local.INFO: Builder
[2023-06-30 07:56:11] local.INFO: {}
[2023-06-30 07:56:11] local.INFO: object
[2023-06-30 07:56:11] local.INFO: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
[2023-06-30 07:56:11] local.INFO: Builder
[2023-06-30 07:56:11] local.INFO: {}
[2023-06-30 07:56:12] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'report_year' in 'group statement' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `banner_clicked_counts` group by report_year order by min(created_at)) {"view":{"view":"/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/filament/tables/resources/views/index.blade.php","data":[]},"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (Spatie\\LaravelIgnition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'report_year' in 'group statement' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `banner_clicked_counts` group by report_year order by min(created_at)) at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(720): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback()
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(422): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run()
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2706): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select()
#3 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2694): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#4 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3230): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}()
#5 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2695): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->onceWithColumns()
#6 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3157): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get()
#7 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3085): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->aggregate()
#8 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1869): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->count()
#9 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/filament/tables/src/Concerns/CanSelectRecords.php(87): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->__call()
#10 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/filament/tables/src/Table.php(85): Filament\\Widgets\\TableWidget->getAllSelectableTableRecordsCount()
#11 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/filament/tables/resources/views/index.blade.php(39): Filament\\Tables\\Table->getAllSelectableRecordsCount()
#12 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(83): include('...')
#13 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(84): App\\Filament\\Widgets\\BannerClickedCountsByYears->Livewire\\ComponentConcerns\\{closure}()
#14 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(59): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->evaluatePath()
#15 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(195): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->get()
#16 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(178): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#17 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(147): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#18 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/filament/support/src/Components/ViewComponent.php(108): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#19 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(116): Filament\\Support\\Components\\ViewComponent->toHtml()
#20 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/resources/views/vendor/filament/widgets/table-widget.blade.php(2): e()
#21 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(83): include('...')
#22 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(84): App\\Filament\\Widgets\\BannerClickedCountsByYears->Livewire\\ComponentConcerns\\{closure}()
#23 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(59): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->evaluatePath()
#24 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(195): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->get()
#25 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(178): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#26 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(147): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#27 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Component.php(235): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#28 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/HydrationMiddleware/RenderView.php(14): Livewire\\Component->output()
#29 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LifecycleManager.php(141): Livewire\\HydrationMiddleware\\RenderView::dehydrate()
#30 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireManager.php(132): Livewire\\LifecycleManager->initialDehydrate()
#31 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(338): Livewire\\LivewireManager->mount()
#32 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/resources/views/vendor/filament/components/widgets.blade.php(20): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic()
#33 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(83): include('...')
#34 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(84): App\\Filament\\Pages\\Dashboard->Livewire\\ComponentConcerns\\{closure}()
#35 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(59): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->evaluatePath()
#36 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(195): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->get()
#37 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(178): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#38 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(147): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#39 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Concerns/ManagesComponents.php(104): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#40 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/resources/views/vendor/filament/pages/dashboard.blade.php(2): Illuminate\\View\\Factory->renderComponent()
#41 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(83): include('...')
#42 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(84): App\\Filament\\Pages\\Dashboard->Livewire\\ComponentConcerns\\{closure}()
#43 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(59): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->evaluatePath()
#44 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(195): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->get()
#45 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(178): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#46 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(147): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#47 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Component.php(235): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#48 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/HydrationMiddleware/RenderView.php(14): Livewire\\Component->output()
#49 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LifecycleManager.php(141): Livewire\\HydrationMiddleware\\RenderView::dehydrate()
#50 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Macros/livewire-view-component.blade.php(3): Livewire\\LifecycleManager->initialDehydrate()
#51 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(109): require('...')
#52 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(110): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem::Illuminate\\Filesystem\\{closure}()
#53 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(58): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->getRequire()
#54 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(69): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
#55 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(70): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->evaluatePath()
#56 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(35): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
#57 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(195): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->get()
#58 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(178): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#59 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(147): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#60 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(69): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#61 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(35): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent()
#62 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(906): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->__construct()
#63 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(875): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse()
#64 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(798): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse()
#65 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#66 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/phpsa/filament-authentication/src/Http/Middleware/ImpersonatingMiddleware.php(15): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#67 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Phpsa\\FilamentAuthentication\\Http\\Middleware\\ImpersonatingMiddleware->handle()
#68 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/filament/filament/src/Http/Middleware/MirrorConfigToSubpackages.php(30): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#69 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Filament\\Http\\Middleware\\MirrorConfigToSubpackages->handle()
#70 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/filament/filament/src/Http/Middleware/DispatchServingFilamentEvent.php(15): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#71 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Filament\\Http\\Middleware\\DispatchServingFilamentEvent->handle()
#72 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#73 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#74 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#75 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#76 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/AuthenticateSession.php(59): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#77 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\AuthenticateSession->handle()
#78 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#79 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()
#80 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#81 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#82 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#83 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#84 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#85 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#86 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#87 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#88 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#89 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#90 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(799): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#91 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(776): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#92 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(740): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#93 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(729): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#94 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#95 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#96 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/DisableBrowserCache.php(19): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#97 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Livewire\\DisableBrowserCache->handle()
#98 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#99 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle()
#100 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#101 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#102 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#103 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#104 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#105 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#106 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#107 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#108 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#109 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#110 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#111 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle()
#112 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#113 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle()
#114 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#115 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#116 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#117 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#118 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'report_year' in 'group statement' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `banner_clicked_counts` group by report_year order by min(created_at)) at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(720): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback()
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(422): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run()
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2706): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select()
#3 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2694): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#4 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3230): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}()
#5 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2695): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->onceWithColumns()
#6 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3157): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get()
#7 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3085): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->aggregate()
#8 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1869): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->count()
#9 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/filament/tables/src/Concerns/CanSelectRecords.php(87): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->__call()
#10 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/filament/tables/src/Table.php(85): Filament\\Widgets\\TableWidget->getAllSelectableTableRecordsCount()
#11 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/storage/framework/views/956e86432388b35be29c645713700cc933ce3a03.php(39): Filament\\Tables\\Table->getAllSelectableRecordsCount()
#12 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(83): include('...')
#13 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(84): App\\Filament\\Widgets\\BannerClickedCountsByYears->Livewire\\ComponentConcerns\\{closure}()
#14 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(59): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->evaluatePath()
#15 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(195): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->get()
#16 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(178): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#17 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(147): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#18 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/filament/support/src/Components/ViewComponent.php(108): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#19 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(116): Filament\\Support\\Components\\ViewComponent->toHtml()
#20 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/storage/framework/views/8b23d773fd85d26be2fc2c6ccf2871214de03bc4.php(10): e()
#21 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(83): include('...')
#22 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(84): App\\Filament\\Widgets\\BannerClickedCountsByYears->Livewire\\ComponentConcerns\\{closure}()
#23 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/RendersLivewireComponents.php(59): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->evaluatePath()
#24 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/FilamentBanners/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(195): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->get()
#25 
...
"}
```

Why report_year was removed from sql and why error ? Not sure is some feature of laravel widget? How can I fix it ?

**ADDITIVE INFO:**
I tried to make:

```
config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', false);
$bannerClickedCountsByLocales= BannerClickedCount::selectRaw("  year(created_at) as report_year,  count(*) as report_count  ")
    ->groupByRaw('report_year')
    ->orderByRaw('min(created_at)');

config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', true);
```

But got the same error.

I modified in
config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'         => 'mysql',
    ...
    'strict'         => false,
    'engine'         => null,
    'options'        => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
```

But the same error anyway...

Comment: Hope you have disable the `strict` mode in the `config/database.php`?

Comment: No, could you please explain how that could raise this problem ? I use mysql 8.0.33-0

Comment: By default, Laravel follows the `strict` behavior with the table to fetch records. when we are using the `GROUP_BY` query that time needs to disable `strict` mode. for more details you can check this Laracast discussion https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/guides/turn-off-only-full-group-by-for-just-one-query-guide

Comment: Please read ADDITIVE INFO